# Scaling Islands on spherical object with constrained radius

Tags: modeling, scripting

I made this spherical object and I want to know how scale the islands smaller without shrinking the sphere(Changing the radius). And if there is a way to do it with a script I would like to know that too as I am just beginning python. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by scaling, do you want to scale islands like this: https://imgur.com/QCGX50v I would start with single faces (no thickness), then mark central faces to each island (you could use a **face map**), then for each island scale that island down and see how much the angular distance changed between the two vertices (e.g. 80% of previous distance) that's your `ratio`. Now for each vertex calculate its new angular distance by multiplying current by the `ratio`, and calculate how it translates to a position on a sphere. Then draw edges outwards from the center and connect them.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, I didn't know the island terminology, so I will edit the question. I will have to learn about face maps.